# SQL Select Distinct Top5 with Order By and Where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where Employees can check assets and each of their checks is recorded in a table.

Now I want to extract the 5 last checked Asset_Ids for a given employee. He might have checked the same asset more than once, each check is recorded in a table -EmployeeLog-

Basically my table has 3 columns :

| Employee_ID | DateChecked | Asset_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06/10/2021 10:56:22 | 1 |
| 1 | 06/10/2021 14:58:25 | 1 |
| 1 | 02/10/2021 13:56:22 | 2 |
| 1 | 06/10/2021 08:56:22 | 1 |
| 1 | 04/10/2021 03:56:22 | 1 |
| 1 | 06/10/2021 02:56:22 | 3 |
| 1 | 06/10/2021 15:56:22 | 2 |
| 1 | 03/10/2021 03:56:22 | 5 |
| 1 | 06/10/2021 03:56:22 | 5 |

I have below query which lists Asset_IDs by check date, but I have to apply distinct and top 5 to this list which I couldn't, any help appreciated.

```
SELECT Asset_ID
FROM EmployeeLog
WHERE EmployeeID = @Emp_ID AND Asset_ID != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
ORDER BY EmployeeLog.DateChecked Desc
```

Comment: Why can't you use distinct and top 5?

Comment: I am using MS SQL server

Comment: When I apply DISTINCT I get this error : ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! (If an Asset_ID has dates both before and after another Asset_ID, how to sort?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY`, and order by first (or last) date.

```
SELECT Asset_ID
FROM EmployeeLog
WHERE EmployeeID = @Emp_ID AND Asset_ID != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GROUP BY Asset_ID
ORDER BY MIN(EmployeeLog.DateChecked) Desc
```

To get the first 5 rows only, do `SELECT TOP 5 Asset_ID` etc.